# I don't understand routing

Tags: php, routes, flightphp

I am trying to learn a PHP framework. But I'm having some difficulties understanding some of the concepts of routing.

I've chosen to use [Flight](http://flightphp.com/). Their homepage shows:

```
require 'flight/Flight.php';

Flight::route('/', function(){
    echo 'hello world!';
});

Flight::start();
```

And I don't understand what they're using `Flight::route...` for. What am I missing? This question isn't even related to Flight. It's related to just routing in general.

Comment: Are you asking what's `::` operator?

Comment: @Leggendario I'm just not sure about routing. I understand what :: is, I just don't get the whole routing thing. And why is there a function inside the routing code on the index page. Why is there routing code inside the index.php page - what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be happening in your file (I'm not familiar with Flight)

the `require 'flight/Flight.php';` is more than likely defining a class for all the routing.

Then `Flight::route();` Is simply using the `route()` method from the class `Flight` without an instance of the class.

```
Flight::route('/', function(){
    echo 'hello world!';
});
```

What happens here is when a route is matched (by matched means the URI of the user matches the URI on your route, in this case `www.yourdomain.com/` will match the `'/'` route) And then the code inside the `function()` callback gets executed.

If you add another route

```
Flight::route('/about', function(){
    echo 'About Us';
});
```

When the user visits `www.yourdomain.com/about` He will get whats inside that route.

Comment: Thank you @Sandman, that helped a lot. So if I understood correctly, this seems to me like how single-page web apps work. We have a bunch of functions/controllers, and one page and on this page we determine which "page" was requested and call the appropriate function (which will display the appropriate content)?

Comment: That is right, although its not restricted to single page websites only, but any website, depends on how you handle it, I often add a router library just to add SEO and route control to an older static website.

As a sample `Flight::route('/', function(){
    include 'index.php';
});` and another route would be 

`Flight::route('/about-us', function(){
    include 'about_us.php';
});`

Now this is a sample of how you would route an old static website, now a days ideally you have a proper controller for each page.

Answer (score 4):

Routing basically maps HTTP requests to your methods/functions.

To put it simply, say you have the route:

```
Flight::route('/page1', function() {
    echo 'page1!';
});
```

This is was basically happens:

1. Client requests `example.com/page1`
2. Server sends query to PHP
3. Your PHP framework parses the request URL
4. Picks the correct route, in our case, `page1/`
5. And finally calls the function you passed in, so basically `echo 'page1';`

Answer (score 2):

Flightphp has a rather comprehensive explanation on how to set up routes [here](http://flightphp.com/learn#routing).

You should see routes as definitions of how to handle different request patterns.
The example on Flight's home page says that if you hit your site root (i.e. /) it will simply return "hello world!" as a response.

If you read further on the Flightphp install page you will notice that all requests are handled by the index.php page.  And thus depending on the routes you define it replies with the relevant response defined for that url request pattern.

Answer (score 1):

route() is a static function it seems, that means it's not specific to the object, i.e. you can't create an object such as

```
$flight = new Flight();
```

and then call

```
$flight->route(...)
```

but rather you call it via the class (not an object, which is a specific implementation of the class). You call static functions of a class by using ::, in this case

```
Flight::route(...)
```

The content of the route just says, when you encounter '/', do 'X'... and in your case 'X' is

```
function(){
    echo 'hello world!';
}
```

in later stages you get to match stuff like

```
'/' (homepage, i.e. "mywebsite.com/")
'/about-us' (About Us page, i.e. "mywebsite.com/about-us")
'/user/{id}' (User page, i.e. you can pass a parameter such as "mywebsite.com/user/taylor" and then get the user data)
```

or whatever you want. And instead of just writing the function into the routing file, you can tell the router to go to a specific function (usually a Controller function) and you can do more stuff there.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Flight::route('/', function(){
    echo 'hello world!';
});
```

This snippet is heart of your project.

This will accept two parameters.

1. Route
2. Method to call on this route call

Consider below code snippet, If you are having your project directory `http://localhost/flight_project/`, when anyone requests this directory, function defined as `'function_here'` will be called.

```
Flight::route('/', 'function_here');
```

If you have defined route like below,

```
Flight::route('/user/', function(){
    // do something here
});
```

when someone access `http://localhost/flight_project/user/`, the above in-line function gets called.

More info [HERE](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/README.md)